# LEAD () Window Function not working in MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-workbench, window-functions

```
SELECT x,y,z,
LEAD(x) OVER(PARTITION BY y,z ORDER BY x) AS column
FROM Table;
```

X here is a timestamp field, This is not working in MYSQL Workbench. I am getting the below error
`( is not valid at this position, expecting EOF,';'`
What is wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

Comment: any workaround to achieve the same result in this version itself?

Comment: Can `x` have duplicate values for a given `y`, `z`?

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are supported in MySQL 8.0 only. In earlier versions, one workaround uses a correlated subquery:

```
select x, y, z,
    (select t1.x from mytable t1 where t1.y = t.y and t1.z = t.z and t1.x > t.x order by t1.x limit 1) as lead_x
from mytable t
```

This somehow assumes no duplicates `(x, y, z)` (otherwise, the result may differ - but the results of the window functions are not stable in that case anyway).

You could also use aggregation rather than `limit`:

```
select x, y, z,
    (select min(t1.x) from mytable t1 where t1.y = t.y and t1.z = t.z and t1.x > t.x ) as lead_x
from mytable t
```